# Ubntu 14.04.3LTS+Radeon HD6950 OUT OF RANGE MONITOR

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, radeon

With standart driver of Ubuntu I can't use my native resolution.
Using the driver from proprietary driver with updates or without, after rebooting i see "Out of range". How can I tune my resolution and frequency
if I can't see anything? Maby I have to tune it before rebooting?
Please Help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a real answer to your question regarding "how to tune my resolution"

But did you try to install the driver from AMD side?
[AMD Driver](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/previous/detail?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064&rev=15.9)

You should install first the "Minimal Video Driver for Graphics Accelerators" and afterwards the "Video Driver for Graphics Accelerators"

As a Alternativ you can check if you can use a other connection to you Monitor. Let's say currently you using HDMI but your PC and Monitor also support DVI give it a try.

Comment: Haven't helped. "Out of range". I have 2 DVI ports 1 HDMI and couple of DP. Now I'm using DVI. I can try another one DVI.

Comment: Can you switch to a other Console with ctrl+alt+F1 odr F2? If yes, what did you get with xrandr command?